# How would I access a txt file and split the links

Tags: c#, parsing

Alright, I have a program that grabs links off of a website and puts it into a txt BUT the links aren't separated onto their own lines and I need to somehow do that without having to manually do it myself, here is the code used to grab the links off of the website, write the links to a text file then grab the txt file and read it.

```
        private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        var client = new WebClient();

        string text = client.DownloadString("https://currentlinks.com");

        File.WriteAllText("C:/ProgramData/oof.txt", text);


        string searchKeyword = "https://foobar.to/showthread.php";
        string fileName = "C:/ProgramData/oof.txt";
        string[] textLines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
        List<string> results = new List<string>();

        foreach (string line in textLines)
        {
            if (line.Contains(searchKeyword))
            {
                results.Add(line);
            }
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var item in results)
            {
                sb.Append(item);
            }

            textBox1.Text = sb.ToString();

            var parsed = textBox1;

            TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("C:/ProgramData/parsed.txt");

            // write lines of text to the file
            tw.WriteLine(parsed);

            // close the stream     
            tw.Close();





        }
    }
```

Comment: what's the txt file contains?

Comment: @Arphile links.

Comment: You mean you are getting links in `text` variable but they are not line separated. They all come in one single line. And you want them to split and write one link on each line to the txt file. Is that you want to achieve?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya exactly. They all start with https if that means anything to you. (i.e. https://forum.to/showthread.php?tid=22305https://forum.to/showthread.php?tid=22405https://forum.to/showthread.php?tid=22318)

Comment: @Chicken show us your txt file sample. we need to know format if you wish to get answer.

Comment: @Arphile sure, here is the textfile and I changed the name of the website for privacy reasons. http://www.fast-files.com/getfile.aspx?file=174580

Comment: returns Sorry, this file does not exist anymore on the server!

Comment: @Arphile https://anonfile.com/kdP2h1jbb5/oof_txt see if that works

Comment: @Arphile tell me if the link worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting all the Links (URLs) in one single string. There is not straight forward way to get all the URLs individually without some assumptions.

With the sample data you shared, I assume that the URLs in the string follow simple URLs format and do not have any fancy stuff in it. They start with `http` and one url does not have any other `http`.

With above assumptions, I suggest following code.

```
// Sample data as shared by the OP
string data = "https://forum.to/showthread.php?tid=22305https://forum.to/showthread.php?tid=22405https://forum.to/showthread.php?tid=22318";

//Splitting the string by string `http` 
var items = data.Split(new [] {"http"},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();

//At this point all the strings in items collection will be without "http" at the start. 
//So they will look like as following.
// s://forum.to/showthread.php?tid=22305
// s://forum.to/showthread.php?tid=22405
// s://forum.to/showthread.php?tid=22318

//So we need to add "http" at the start of each of the item as following.
items = items.Select(i => "http" + i).ToList();

// After this they will become like following.
// https://forum.to/showthread.php?tid=22305
// https://forum.to/showthread.php?tid=22405
// https://forum.to/showthread.php?tid=22318

//Now we need to create a single string with newline character between two items so 
//that they represent a single line individually.
var text = String.Join("\r\n", items);

// Then write the text to the file.
File.WriteAllText("C:/ProgramData/oof.txt", text);
```

This should help you resolve your issue.

Comment: Ok, I ported over the code you have given me and I changed a few things like changing the string data to now equal whatever is in my textbox, the only problem is this line of code
    items = item.Select(i => "http"+i);

item doesn't exist in the current context. I looked around to try and find an issue. Couldn't find one about that specific set of code.

Comment: replace `items = item.Select(i => "http" + i);` with `items = items.Select(i => "http" + i);`. I just updated my answer

Comment: I did and now I get  `CS0266  C# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: Sorry... for the inconvenience.  Please use `var items = data.Split(new [] {"http"},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();`  and `items = items.Select(i => "http" + i).ToList();` I have updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

## .Split way

Could you use `yourString.Split("https://");`?

Example:

```
//This simple example assumes that all links are https (not http)
string contents = "https://www.example.com/dogs/poodles/poodle1.htmlhttps://www.example.com/dogs/poodles/poodle2.html";

const string Prefix = "https://";
var linksWithoutPrefix = contents.Split(Prefix, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

//using System.Linq
var linksWithPrefix = linksWithoutPrefix.Select(l => Prefix + l);
foreach (var match in linksWithPrefix)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match);
}
```

## Regex way

Another option is to use reg exp.

**Failed - cannot find/write the right regex ... got to go now**

```
string contents = "http://www.example.com/dogs/poodles/poodle1.htmlhttp://www.example.com/dogs/poodles/poodle2.html";

//From https://regexr.com/
var rgx = new Regex(@"(?<Protocol>\w+):\/\/(?<Domain>[\w@][\w.:@]+)\/?[\w\.?=%&=\-@/$,]*");
var matches = rgx.Matches(contents);

foreach(var match in matches )
{
    Console.WriteLine(match);
}

//This finds 'http://www.example.com/dogs/poodles/poodle1.htmlhttp' (note the htmlhttp at the end
```

Comment: Could you explain in a little more depth on how I could use that?